# Prevent scrolled Hero from jumping on top of the app bar

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a `Hero` that can be scrolled so that part of it is offscreen. When I trigger a transition, it appears to abruptly jump on top of the `AppBar` and then jumps back under it when the transition is reversed. How do I force the `AppBar` to stay on top of the `Hero`?

[image: video]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Example(),
    theme: new ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.orange),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ));
}

Widget positionHeroOverlay(BuildContext context, Widget overlay, Rect rect, Size size) {
  final RelativeRect offsets = new RelativeRect.fromSize(rect, size);
  return new Positioned(
    top: offsets.top,
    right: offsets.right,
    bottom: offsets.bottom,
    left: offsets.left,
    child: overlay,
  );
}

class LogoPageRoute extends MaterialPageRoute<Null> {
  LogoPageRoute(this.colors) : super(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Flutter Logo'),
        ),
        body: new ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: new Hero(
            tag: colors,
            child: new FlutterLogo(colors: colors),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );

  /// The color of logo to display
  final MaterialColor colors;

  @override
  final Duration transitionDuration = const Duration(seconds: 1);
}

final List<MaterialColor> swatches = [
  Colors.blue,
  Colors.orange,
  Colors.green,
];

class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('All Logos'),
      ),
      body: new ListView(
        children: swatches.map((MaterialColor colors) {
          return new InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context, new LogoPageRoute(colors));
            },
            child: new Hero(
              tag: colors,
              child: new FlutterLogo(size: 360.0, colors: colors),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Wrap your `AppBar` in a `Hero` to force it to stay on top.

```
  appBar: new PreferredSize(
    child: new Hero(
      tag: AppBar,
      child: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('All Logos'),
      ),
    ),
    preferredSize: new AppBar().preferredSize,
  ),
```

For the `AppBar` of the detail page, I would recommend forcing the back button to be displayed so that it appears at the same time that the page title changes.

```
    appBar: new PreferredSize(
      child: new Hero(
        tag: AppBar,
        child: new AppBar(
          leading: const BackButton(),
          title: new Text('Flutter Logo'),
        ),
      ),
      preferredSize: new AppBar().preferredSize,
    ),
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: video]

Comment: You loose the sliding transition of the app bar though.

Comment: Yes, I'm hoping someone can submit a better answer :)

Comment: Considering that Hero uses the Navigator overlay, I don't think it's possible to have the exact same animation without lots of work or unmaintable code.

Comment: Navigation bar jumps during hero transition on iPhone X and above. Here's a workaround: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27848#issuecomment-484970205

Answer (score 3):

i've fixed it here https://github.com/zombie6888/scrolled_hero by providing bottom and top offset to hero animation builder

[image]

Comment: what about bigger photo than apbbar and bottombar

Comment: What do you mean? The photo is bigger. Anyway this workaround doesn't always work. It depends on scroll offset and navigation. You can adjust the flightShuttleBuilder function to support your case.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
flightShuttleBuilder:
                                (BuildContext flightContext,
                                    Animation<double> animation,
                                    HeroFlightDirection flightDirection,
                                    BuildContext fromHeroContext,
                                    BuildContext toHeroContext) {
                              // make hero more smoothly
                              final Hero hero = (flightDirection ==
                                      HeroFlightDirection.pop
                                  ? fromHeroContext.widget
                                  : toHeroContext.widget) as Hero;

                              return hero.child;
                            },
```